# Potential leak in allocating memory to a property

Tags: iphone, ios, button, memory-management, retain

I was digging into memory management, i found this.

I created a property button.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button;
```

In ViewdidLoad method, i have written following code.

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
[self.view addsubView:self.button];
```

Doing XCode analyze, i am getting potential leak of an allocated variable on line 33 i.e; self.button.

Why does this happens? If i create a local UIButton and assign it to self.button and use it, then there is no potential leak. If i alloc memory to self.button or any property variables, it leaks.

Thanks
Jithen

Comment: just for conformance... try with `strong`

Comment: Same with Strong too..

Comment: So, need to [release] many answers saying this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a value to self.button calls the synthesized setter method:

```
- (void)setButton:(UIButton *)button;
```

Because you added the "retain" attribute to your property declaration, the synthesized setter will automatically call "retain" on the object that is set.  This ups the retain count of the object.

Calling "alloc" on UIButton also ups the object's retain count.

So doing self.button = [UIButton alloc] essentially will up your retain count by 2.  That's why there's a potential leak.

You can fix this by doing either:

```
self.button = [[[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)] autorelease];
```

or

```
UIButton *temp = [[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
self.button = temp;
[temp release];
```

or

```
_button = [[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
```

Comment: So if i use retain property, its retain count will be 1 automatically.

Comment: If you use the retain property, whenever you set that property using "self.button = " or "[self setButton:]" the object you're setting it with will have its retain count incremented by 1.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination. But i tried removing retain property and tried with assign. Assign property should not increase the retain count on doing self.button = . But even here it is throwing potential leak.

Comment: In that case there's a leak because you're still doing +1 on the retain count of the new button when you do [UIButton alloc], but you're never releasing it.  By setting your property to "assign" you're basically saying that that property doesn't own the object so it won't be responsible for dropping its retain count in dealloc.  When you do [UIButton alloc] you need to release that object yourself (regardless of if it's stored in your property or not).

Comment: Remember that when you set a property to "retain" the setter automatically calls "release" on the object before it gets replaced.  So when you call setButton: it calls "release" on _button and then sets _button to the new button, and then retains the new button.  So when you say self.button = nil, it actually releases the previous button.  So when you change to "assign", that won't happen anymore, so the [UIButton alloc] you assign to it won't get released (and will leak).

Comment: So final conclusion is i should not allocate memory for property variables like retain, assign, strong any variables.. i can assign the  property to local variable like "self.button = button". If the self.button is set with retain, self.button retain count will be increased by 1. If the self.button is assign, there wont be any change in its retain count. If it is copy, then we have to release [self.button release] instead of just making nil in dealloc method. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

`@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button;` using this you are retaining object.

Now using `self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];` you are allocating memory and retain count is increased by 1.

So in you case this is a leak as retain count of object is increased. In case if you have local object and you alloc then again releasing it . So there is no extra retain count and there is no leak.

**Abstarct**

When you use factory method or create object using **alloc,new,retain,copy,mutableCopy** your object has **+1 retain count** every time. You own object in this case. You are responsible for releasing it. So you need to **release** object after you finish using object which cause **-1 retain count** to object.

**EDIT**

Now you are doing

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIButton *button;
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[self.button release];
```

Here you are accessing object using self which invokes on variable of your created property. You are sending +1 retain count over property object so it becomes 2 as property it self has getter and setters. So instead of doing this you can use instance variable like this.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIButton *button;
_button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[_button release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If i try with assign instead of retain, i am getting potential leak. But it should not. Isn't it.

Comment: If you use assign and still you alloc your object it is a leak as you are not yet releasing it.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) UIButton *button;    After allocating memory to self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init]; I am releasing [self.button release]. Even then it is throwing potential leak..

Answer (score 1):

Before ARC, you would normally do this for a `retain` variable:

```
UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
self.button = btn;    // property increases retain count because of its declaration as "retain"
[btn release];
```

with ARC, you would probably do this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIButton* button;

self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initwithFrame : CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
[self.view addsubView:self.button];
```

the second example illustrates that you don't really need to have your property retain the button (via `retain` or `strong`) because when you add a subview to a view container, the containing view will retain the new child.

Of course, there are some exceptions.  Sometimes, you might actually want to remove your view (button) from the superview, but not let it be released, because you'll add it back later.

So, sometimes, it's valid to retain UI objects.  Usually, it's not necessary, though.

**Update:** I would like to comment here that this kind of *problem* is why Apple wants people to use ARC.  This is a really basic memory management scenario, that continues to foil lots and lots of new developers.  At this point, there's very little reason for beginning iOS developers **not** to be using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UIButton` instance is being retained twice. `[UIButton alloc]` creates a retained instance and the `button` property is retaining it when assigned via `self.button`. With MRC (Manual Reference Counting) code you need to release anything you retain.

When you create the button do the following:

```
UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...] autorelease];
self.button = button;
```

Alternatively, use the preferred creator method for `UIButton':

```
self.button [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.button.frame = CGRectMake(...);
```

You also need to release the button wherever you clean up objects assigned to your properties. You're coding will be much simpler if you use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) instead of MRC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have released it or not but whenever we alloc memory, we have to release it(if ARC is not used in your project).
So just release it in dealloc like this:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [button release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```